# Elegant way to get object that Box3 was set from, for simple camera collision detection in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to get the object I used to set a Box3 (with Box.setFromObject) once the Box3 registers a hit.

Currently, I'm pushing the Box3 to an array, and then pushing the object (that the Box3 was set from) to a different array:

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.name = "box0";
scene.add( cube );
var bbox = new THREE.Box3();
bbox.setFromObject( cube );
bboxList.push(bbox);
bboxObjectNameList.push(cube.name);
```

Then checking both arrays every frame:

```
  for(i=0;i<bboxList.length;i++)
  {
    if(bboxList[i].containsPoint(camera.position)) {
      hitName = bboxObjectNameList[i];
      hitObj = scene.getObjectByName(hitName);
    }
  }
```

Does anyone know a better way to find the object that the Box3 was set from?

Three.js r84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about the three.js javascript objects is that they are, well... *javascript objects*. This means you can add any property you want to a Box3, including the "object they are set from".

To follow three.js conventions, I'd suggest using a *.userData* wrapper property for any custom properties you add. This avoids naming collisions with any internal three.js properties that might be added in future versions.

Practically, this would make your code look something like

```
var bbox = new THREE.Box3();
bbox.setFromObject( cube );
bbox.userData = { sourceObject: cube };

...

if (bboxList[i].containsPoint(camera.position)) {
  hitObj = bboxList[i].userData.sourceObject;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Paul-Jan. Fairly new to Three.js and I keep forgetting about the freedom of js objects! You are right, they are a great thing.